# Numpy float storage into Dataframe seems to be wrongly managed

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, floating-point, precision

I just used this dataframe to test an algorithm for statistics:

```
d1=pd.DataFrame([[0.1,0.2],[0.3,0.4],[0.5,0.6],[0.7,0.8],[0.9,0.81],[0.91,0.82],[0.93,0.94],[0.95,0.96],[0.97,0.98],[0.99,1]])
```

recalling:

- `d1.iloc[0,1]` yields `0.20000000000000001`
- `d1.iloc[2,1]` yields `0.59999999999999998`

performing

```
 d1=pd.DataFrame([[0.1,0.2],[0.3,0.4],[0.5,0.6],[0.7,0.8],[0.9,0.81],[0.91,0.82],[0.93,0.94],[0.95,0.96],[0.97,0.98],[0.99,1]]).astype(np.float)
```

or

```
   d1=pd.DataFrame([[0.1,0.2],[0.3,0.4],[0.5,0.6],[0.7,0.8],[0.9,0.81],[0.91,0.82],[0.93,0.94],[0.95,0.96],[0.97,0.98],[0.99,1]], dtype=np.float)
```

doesn't change the results

On the other hand, `b=np.float(0.2)` and `c=np.float(0.6)` give correct values when recalled.

Did I miss something or is there really a problem with data management in pandas? It is very important to me as I need precision for my data.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't "data management". It's how [floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) work. Rounding isn't exclusive to numpy or pandas; all software systems are prone to this. If you really want to see an example of this, just look at `d1.iloc[0,1] - b`.

Comment: I did not mean that specific elements of the df were wrong. All are. While the same numbers in numpy.floats are not wrong. So this is not a fp number problem. this happens only when np.floats are extracted from pandas.

Comment: First, note that `np.float` is Python's builtin `float`, so we might as well just compare `d1.iloc[0,1]` to `0.2`.  Then note that `d1.iloc[0,1] == 0.2` is `True`.  The floating point values stored in memory are exactly the same.   The difference is in how the values are printed.  Python's code to create a representation of a floating point value as a string is smarter than numpy's code.  The Python code uses the shortest string that uniquely identifies the floating point value.  When converted to a 64 bit floating point value, `0.20000000000000001` and `0.2` result in the *same* 64 bit value.

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.array` rather than pandas, compare the display of one element:

```
x=np.array([[0.1,0.2],[0.3,0.4],[0.5,0.6],[0.7,0.8],[0.9,0.81],[0.91,0.82],[0.93,0.94],[0.95,0.96],[0.97,0.98],[0.99,1]])

x[0,1]
Out[47]: 0.20000000000000001

float(x[0,1])
Out[48]: 0.2

np.float(x[0,1])   # np.float32
Out[49]: 0.2

np.float64(x[0,1])
Out[50]: 0.20000000000000001
```

When showing the full 64, we see that extra nonzero values off at the end, but with the short 32 type we don't.

This the same information that Warren provided in comments.

Comment: Ok, thanks to both of you. So that's a matter or representations, that should not affect calculation, right? So how do I do to avoid these values to be printed as such in documents from pandas? just convert to float or np.float32 in the end? What if the values are outside of their ranges? Because I understand the technical point, but there is a problem because these values can be printed. Then they become a mistake, even when in calculation, they are right, because they can be your final result. this is particularly annoying when using values that everyone knows they should be rounded.